# How to i check if state is changed in a react test?

Tags: reactjs, testing

I am  very new to testing in React. I update the state at the end of my sort function. I just can figure out how to get the state from the Wrapper I am creating.

```
test('Sorting Data No Change', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(render(<Table headers={[
                       {name:"ID", prop: "id"},
                       {name:"Manufacturer", prop: "manufacturer"},
                       {name:"Model", prop: "model"}
                       ]}
              data={data}
              bold ="Ford"
              upper="Model" />);


        );


  console.log(wrapper.instance().sort("asend", "id"));
  expect(wrapper.state.filtered).equals(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take the state before and after the update and check them like so :

```
test('Sorting Data No Change', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(render(<Table headers={[
                       {name:"ID", prop: "id"},
                       {name:"Manufacturer", prop: "manufacturer"},
                       {name:"Model", prop: "model"}
                       ]}
              data={data}
              bold ="Ford"
              upper="Model" />);


        );

   let filterState = wrapper.state.filtered;

  // update the state

  wrapper.instance().sort("asend", "id");

// check the new state equals to the past state

  expect(wrapper.state.filtered).equals(filterState);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to test a component. You can mount the parent, simulate clicks, and make assertions against the parent `state` and children `props`. Or you can mount the child, manipulate `props` to simulate sort clicks, and make assertions against the changes in the prop data. **Which one to do is ultimately up to you and your work flow**.

That said, I like to test two components in one `.test.js` file when the two are inherently linked as one (meaning, one can't function without the other). So in the example below, I'll be making assertions against the parent `state` and some assertions against some children elements when its `props` change.

**Working example** (click the `Tests` tab to run the tests):

[image: Edit Testing Parent State]

What's happening in the test (you can also do this is in the `Browser` tab to get an idea of the flow):

1. Simulating an initial click on the "sort" icon next to the `id` table header
2. Making assertions against the parent state: `data`, `sortByName` and `sortByType`; and then making some assertions against the children's visible elements (in this case, making sure that the "sort" icon next to the `id` changes to an arrow up/down depending upon the click sequence -- first click is `desc`, second click is `asc`, and then it toggles between the two upon subsequent clicks).
3. Clicking the `Clear Filters` button to reset back to `initialState`.

---

**components/App/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "../Table";
import { app } from "./App.module.scss";

export const initialState = {
  data: [
    {
      id: "1",
      manufacturer: "Ford",
      model: "Mustang"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      manufacturer: "Toyota",
      model: "Tundra"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      manufacturer: "Honda",
      model: "Civic"
    }
  ],
  headers: ["id", "manufacturer", "model"],
  sortByName: "",
  sortByType: ""
};

class App extends Component {
  state = initialState;

  clearFilters = () => this.setState(initialState);

  handleSort = (sortByName, sortByType) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: Array.from(prevState.data).sort((a, b) =>
        sortByType === "asc"
          ? a[sortByName].localeCompare(b[sortByName])
          : b[sortByName].localeCompare(a[sortByName])
      ),
      sortByName,
      sortByType
    }));
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className={app}>
      <Table
        {...this.state}
        clearFilters={this.clearFilters}
        handleSort={this.handleSort}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**components/App/__tests__/App.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { configure, mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import App, { initialState } from "../index";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("App", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    // before each test, reset the wrapper to initial state
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
  });

  it("should render without errors", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("Table").exists()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find("FaSort").length).toEqual(3);
  });

  it("sorts data by a table header sort button", () => {
    // a function to simulate a sort click on the icon next to the "id" table header
    const sortById = () => wrapper.find("button#sort-id").simulate("click");

    // simulating an initial sort click
    sortById();

    // next to id should should now be a "sort down" arrow icon
    expect(wrapper.find("FaSortDown").length).toEqual(1);

    // the "sortByName" state should now be "id"
    expect(wrapper.state("sortByName")).toEqual("id");
    // the "sortByType" state should now be "desc"
    expect(wrapper.state("sortByType")).toEqual("desc");

    // the "data" state should be now sorted by desc id
    expect(wrapper.state("data")).toEqual([
      {
        id: "3",
        manufacturer: "Honda",
        model: "Civic"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        manufacturer: "Toyota",
        model: "Tundra"
      },
      {
        id: "1",
        manufacturer: "Ford",
        model: "Mustang"
      }
    ]);

    // simulating the sort click again
    sortById(); 

    // next to the "id" should be now be a "sort up" arrow icon
    expect(wrapper.find("FaSortUp").length).toEqual(1);

    // the "sortByType" state should now be "asc"
    expect(wrapper.state("sortByType")).toEqual("asc");

    // the "data" state should be sorted by the asc id
    expect(wrapper.state("data")).toEqual([
      {
        id: "1",
        manufacturer: "Ford",
        model: "Mustang"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        manufacturer: "Toyota",
        model: "Tundra"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        manufacturer: "Honda",
        model: "Civic"
      }
    ]);

    // clicking 'clear filters' button to reset to initial state
    wrapper.find("button#clear-filters").simulate("click");

    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual(initialState);
  });
});
```

**components/Table/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { FaSort, FaSortUp, FaSortDown } from "react-icons/fa"; //
import {
  table,
  thead,
  th,
  td,
  headerColum,
  sort,
  clear
} from "./Table.module.scss";

const Table = ({
  clearFilters,
  data,
  handleSort,
  headers,
  sortByName,
  sortByType
}) => (
  <>
    <table className={table}>
      <thead className={thead}>
        <tr>
          {headers.map(name => (
            <th className={th} key={name}>
              <span className={headerColum}>{name}</span>
              <button
                id={`sort-${name}`}
                className={sort}
                type="button"
                onClick={() =>
                  handleSort(
                    name,
                    !sortByType || sortByName !== name || sortByType === "asc"
                      ? "desc"
                      : "asc"
                  )
                }
                key={name}
              >
                {sortByName !== name ? (
                  <FaSort />
                ) : sortByType === "asc" ? (
                  <FaSortUp style={{ color: "#0093fc" }} />
                ) : (
                  <FaSortDown style={{ color: "#0093fc" }} />
                )}
              </button>
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map(({ id, manufacturer, model }) => (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td className={td}>{id}</td>
            <td className={td}>{manufacturer}</td>
            <td className={td}>{model}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button
      type="button"
      id="clear-filters"
      className={clear}
      onClick={clearFilters}
    >
      Clear Filters
    </button>
  </>
);

Table.propTypes = {
  clearFilters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      manufacturer: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      model: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired,
  handleSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  headers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  sortByName: PropTypes.string,
  sortByType: PropTypes.string
};

export default Table;
```

---

## Notes

I'm using some ES6 shorthand syntax, so if it looks a little confusing, then here are some notes:

- The [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (`cond ? true : false`) is shorthand for `if/else`.
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows you to "spread out" an object's properties. Since `state` is an object with properties, we can do this: `<Table {...this.state} />` which would be shorthand for: `<Table data={this.state.data} sortByName={this.state.sortByName} />`
- Since `setState` is asynchronous, I'm utilizing the [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) to make sure the state is up-to-date when it's called: `this.setState(prevState => ({ ... })`. When dealing with large data and/or multiple `this.setState()` calls, this ensures the state is accurate (synchronous) when evaluated. In addition, I'm using parenthesis `()` to implicitly `return` the result of the function as an object `{}`, for example: `const example = () => ({ name: "hello" });` would return an `object` with a `name` property: `const test = example(): // returns { name: "hello" }`.
- Since `.sort()` mutates the array, [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) creates a new instance of the current array and mutates the instance instead of the source. By design, React doesn't handle mutable state (it just won't update/rerender the component if the state is mutated). By creating an instance, we're overriding the old array with this new array instance.
- Utilizing [localCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort by the specified `sortByType`; for example `a[id].localCompare(b[id])` will sort the `a` object by a `b`'s id string in ascending order. By reversing this, you can get the descending order: `b[id].localCompare(a[id])`.
- [Object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is shorthand for bypassing dot notation: `const target = event.target;`, would be: `const { target } = event;`. I'm mostly using this in the `Table` component, where I'm pulling out the `{ property }` from the properties that were passed down: `<Table {...this.state} />`
- Utilizing enzyme's `mount` function instead of `shallow` because mount shows the entire DOM tree-structure; whereas shallow only shows root-level DOM structures.

For example, `mount` would look like this:

```
<App>
 <div>example</div>
 <Child>
  <p>I'm a child!</p>
  <SecondChild>
    <p>I'm a secondary child</p>
  <SecondChild>
 <Child>
</App>
```

Whereas `shallow`, would look like this:

```
<App>
 <div>example</div>
 <Child />
</App>
```

Since I'm making assertions against both root and child level components, I use `mount` over `shallow` -- you can see this structure by using the enzyme `debug` function: `console.log(wrapper.debug());`.

Some additional resources:

[enzyme documentation](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/)

[jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect)