# React check if state has been changed

Tags: reactjs

Here I have a state which contains of client info

```js
const { info, setInfo, onPostInfoChanges } = useContext(ClientInfos);
```

Below it, is a function that post or put new `infos` to server

```js
const onSubmitHandler = async (model) => {
    const emptyInputs = invalidInputs(model);
    if (emptyInputs.length) {
      emptyInputs.forEach((key) =>
        setError((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: true }))
      );
    } else {
      const response = await Save(model);
      setAllClient((currentArray) => [response, ...currentArray]);
      closeModal();
      setError({});
    }
};
```

I wanna execute `onSubmitHandler` when info state changed. `onPostInfoChanges` is a function that handle input change event.

Comment: this might be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60343518/how-to-i-check-if-state-is-changed-in-a-react-test

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use useEffect hook with `info` as dependency.

It should look something like this,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // Your code that you want to run whenever the info stat is changed
    ...
    onSubmitHandler(model)
    ...
},[info])
```

I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect` hook with `info` as a dependency to execute the onSubmitHandler when the `info` state is changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  onSubmitHandler(model)
},[info])
```

Now, this useEffect hook identifies the change in the info state and execute the onSubmitHandler.

Refer to [this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for more information about React useEffect hook